# Why Custom CSS file doesn't work anymore?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I'm building an eCommerce website using PHP, Bootstrap, and Jquery. I created this header file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title><?php getTitle() ?></title>
       <!-- FONTAWESOME CDN -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
       <!-- BOOTSTRAP CDN -->
       <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
       <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/templates/index.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
```

Then I created the custom CSS file as you can see above. This file works with me on the login page. But now every time I want to **custom something on bootstrap** or just **adding custom CSS**, it **doesn't work** anymore.
PS: the path is true.

Comment: Share with us the paths of `CSS` file and the current `PHP` page path.

Comment: Debug your issue - remove *all* content except the one `<link rel` and add a bit of html to show it works.  By *all content*  I mean also all the `<meta` and <title` tags as well as `doctype` `html` `head` (might not be 100% valid but at least you'll find the issue)

Answer (score 2):

no need to use "/" for path to CSS, so you can write like this

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/templates/index.css"/>`

Comment: I fixed this problem but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can comes from PHP error when he tries to execute the function `getTitle()` he found a problem so that the navigator will not read the next lines after `<title>` tag. So that, try to remove it from the title tag `<title></title>` to make sure that the problem is not that.

Comment: I deleted the title tag. But the same problem.

Comment: Di you delete the PHP function `getTitle()` too ? If yes, please share with us the projects files structures to make sure that everything is going good with the paths.